# htaccess redirect 410 for URL that contains com_virtuemart

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, http-status-code-410

In `.htaccess` how can I do a 410 redirection for all URLs with `com_virtuemart`.

Anything like:

```
index.php?page=shop.browse&option=com_virtuemart&search=GO&search_category=63&keyword1=43
```

Answer (score 2):

**com_virtuemart** is part of QueryString in your url. You can use the following to redirect urls with **com_** to 410 error status.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} com_virtuemart [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

Comment: You can also use the "shorthand" `G` (`gone`) flag instead of `R=410`. (410 Gone)

Comment: it does not work
with : /index.php/component/com_virtuemart/itemid,6/category_id,56/flypage,flypage.tpl/page,shop.product_details/product_id,2253/

I am getting a 404

Comment: The uri you posted does not include a query string. Querystring starts with a **?** question mark.  See the url in your OP.

Comment: anyway I get many URL like that in my redirect  plugin that collect all redirections, without any ? in it
they are under 404 errors in Google webmaster tools :
/index.php/component/com_virtuemart/Itemid,26/keyword1,45/page,shop.browse/search,GO/search_category,51/
or /index.php/component/com_virtuemart/Itemid,24/category_id,52/page,shop.browse/
it should be a condition with com_virtuemart as a part of URL but not only as QUERY_STRING

Comment: maybe 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} com_virtuemart [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} com_virtuemart [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]